# SQL Query -Sum a value column grouped by Country not include ‘nan’ and only for year 2023

Tags: sql, group-by

I’m stuck on this SQL query. I'm a newbie so it's probably an easy fix but I've been trying for 2 hrs and not making any progress.

These are the columns:

```
Country (string), 
created_year (float), 
video_views (float)
```

Task: sum the `video_views` column grouped by `country` (where country does not equal 'nan') and only for year 2023.0.

Here’s the code I’m using for my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Country,
    created_year,
    SUM(video_views)
FROM
    my-data-project-august-2023.youtube_global_2023.youtube_statistics_2023
GROUP BY
    created_year, Country
ORDER BY
    Created_year
```

And these are the results I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ8N3.png)

The countries in the list are not grouped because duplicates are showing.

The years are listed individually and did not group together.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please post the text directly and not images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be even better if you could provide screenshots of the original data and desired results (you can use Excel to create examples).

Below is an attempt:

```
SELECT Country, SUM(video_views) 
FROM my-data-project-august-2023.youtube_global_2023.youtube_statistics_2023
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
AND created_year = 2023.0 --This 2023.0 needs to be set according to the actual value.
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: Thank you! :J)  I attached the screenshot of the data results.  I wouldn't let me paste it in the body.  I'm pasting a sample of the original data.

Comment: It's taking awhile to download thedataset to to Sheets but I will post it as soon as it finishes.

Comment: OMG!  Using part of your query, I added a little at a time and got the results I was looking for.  I goofed looking for 2023.0 as I found out that there is no 2023.0 in the dataset so when I used 2022.0 I got closer. Here is the code I used:.     SELECT
  Country,
  created_year,
  SUM(video_views)
FROM my-data-project-august-2023.youtube_global_2023.youtube_statistics_2023 AS youtube
WHERE 
  created_year = 2022.0
AND Country <> 'nan'
GROUP BY
  created_year,
  Country

Comment: @Stacie  - When providing data, you only need to provide some sample test data, there is no need for all the data. At the same time, pay attention to the confidentiality of the data.

Comment: @Stacie  Yes, I need to know which columns the results need to contain in order to provide the correct answer.

Comment: The data is from a bigquery public dataset. Ill try to to copy the text from the results as text and paste it from my laptop. Did i say thank you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Good to hear that you have started at one point.

As you are filtering data for 2023 or 2022, you can remove including year in the select and group by Clauses to increase your query performance. Also, as you have tried ORDER BY Year. There will only be one year and sorting based on this column won't be of much use.

```
SELECT Country 
    ,SUM(video_views) as Total_Views
FROM my-data-project-august-2023.youtube_global_2023.youtube_statistics_2023
WHERE created_year=2023.0 AND
    Country<>'nan'
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Country
```

And you can paste just few lines of your output/ input to make the question more clear. Hope this helps. And please do accept the answers.

And you can't use both DISTINCT and GROUP BY at a time